# Iphone marker detection in augmented reality

Tags: iphone, xcode, augmented-reality, marker

(Sorry for bad english)

Hi everyone,

I am curious about the architecture of marker detection so i started to google it. I want an iphone application (i.e. xcode project), with source codes of course, about marker detection in AR. I want codes because i tried to execute the app in my iphone then i'll dig the code in order to understand the architecture. I have been searching this issue in 2 days. I found a few examples but most of them are interested in AR generally not specifically in marker detection. Some of my research findings are bottom of the paragraph btw. 1 or 2 apps found in marker detection but in the apps there is no marker so i didn't try. I searched github and codes.google. I also searched here but i didn't succeed enough. To sum up, i need help:) Can you help me?

Thanks

Toolkits:
ARToolkit
NyARToolkit
flARToolkit
Wikitude etc.

WebPages:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/07/01/augmented-reality-on-the-iphone-using-nyartoolkit-w-code/

Comment: Check out OpenCV.  It's an open source computer vision library created by Intel.  Really powerful highly optimized algorithms for applications like yours.

Answer (score 2):

check Out Arkit Demo and Mixare,

https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone

https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/

In Mixare,AugmentedRealityViewController.you will find a method

- (void)updateLocations:

you will find how marker is detected and place on iPhone Screen.
Method name is same in ARKit also.